# Rails Tutorial, Hartl - ch. 10 - password/activate - Email link not redirecting to Heroku Site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, sendgrid

The links that are sent in the password reset and account activation are being sent in the email, but when I click on them, they are not being redirected to my Heroku app and the browser gets stuck at "about:blank". Am I missing something? They look like this:

```
<a href="https://u1655481.ct.sendgrid.net/wf/click?upn=mvuowIo3LtfxyVBtmnV5znO-2BvLApX4OWlh043PlY34nTdRmVM6vveMB03kyw9RkDUEvA28BSK-2BUBSWODF5yWFrC-2BNt0QPl2osMcVH1xzWtqraK-2BhdDaKAPwzziqS4B54pYcNarDcDTbKmyaLj-2BTSmnoiNl2BT8VqnMMrP7p8su4-3D_MQpxKXFxFonjeh1cARHVt6njcLV6H54PXEoHxOAloIou4oLyvkm9uLyulhz86uohdzxbBJHb-2Bu9ZUCPw-2FkxT7fW8mZO5dW2jHztjZZckPwUqZd9lZaxI8eitFNUyzb6GNUFVejIw76kkAOqYCQ5M4cZXTVJClAoWekh6xUxZ9NUOMK-2B-2Fx5D-2BfOqUmHW462oyh61psTTWPiu0GRg2HpWs0NezfSCN6Kh938A8OJLHBUQ-3D" target="_blank" class="">Reset password</a>
```

Here is my app/views/user_mailer/password_reset.html.erb

```
<h1>Password reset</h1>

<p>To reset your password click the link below:</p>

<%= link_to "Reset password", edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token,
                                                  email: @user.email) %>

<p>This link will expire in two hours.</p>

<p>
If you did not request your password to be reset, please ignore this email and
your password will stay as it is.
</p>
```

Comment: This might be a SendGrid, and not a programming problem. Have you tried using that link directly in a browser?  If it doesn't work, then the problem is with SendGrid.  If it does work, maybe it's a formatting issue with your email client.

Comment: Looks like it is now working after I changed around some settings, however SendGrid so very slow, like 20 minutes to send an email. Is this because I am on the free version?

Comment: @lluis what changes did you make? I think I have the same problem

Answer (score 6):

Looks like the URL that you pass over to SendGrid is `http://<your+heroku+app>.herokuapp.com/password_resets/...`, so you'd need to make sure you specify your app's name instead of having `http://<your+heroku+app>`. If you're using SMTP, check to see if you have your config.action_mailer.default_url_options (in `config/production.rb`) setup properly:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://appname.herokuapp.com' }
```

Comment: I was stuck in same issue with sendgrid and your answer helped me out with quick fix.

Answer (score 2):

did same error and felt so LOL when I realized the solution:

1. check your `config/environments/production.rb` [Listing 10.56](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation_password_reset#code-sendgrid_config)
2. update `host = '<your+heroku+app>.herokuapp.com'` with your APP's name (in my case was `host = 'twitterdave.herokuapp.com'` )

Let me know if it helps